# How can I determine if a debt consolidation offer is real or a scam?

Tags: debt-reduction, fraud, loan-consolidation

A friend of mine recently attempted to go though debt consolidation.  He received a phone call and was offered really good terms to consolidate his current debts.  A promise was made that the company would negotiate with the creditors and reduce their debt by nearly 60%.  This included 30k in Student loan debt and about 15k in other debt.

They were advised to stop making payments on their debts and send the money instead to the debt consolidation company.  The company said it would then pay off the debts and issue the a loan for the reduced amount.  Well 2 months went by with them sending the required payments via certified check.  In this time they defaulted on their car loan and their student loans.  The company said they would take care of it not to worry.  Even took contact information for the companies.

Finally the company told them they were sorry they were not able to help them.  That the money they had sent was for the application and approval process.    The company is now out of business and the AG is investigating but the investigators said that any recovery was unlikely. What steps can people take to be sure that the debt consolidation offer is real?

Answer (score 13):

I believe no-one who's in a legal line of business would tell you to default voluntarily on your obligations.

Once you get an offer that's too good to be true, and for which you have to do something that is either illegal or very damaging to you - it is probably a scam.

Also, if someone requires you to send any money without a prior written agreement - its probably a scam as well, especially in such a delicate matter as finances. Your friend now should also be worried about identity theft as he voluntary gave tons of personal information to these people.

Bottom line - if it walks like a duck, talks like a duck and looks like a duck, it is probably a duck. Your friend had all the warning signs other than a huge neon light saying "Scam" pointing at these people, and he still went through it.

For real debt consolidation companies, research well: online reviews, BBB ratings and reviews, time in business, etc. If you can't find any - don't deal with them. Also, if you get promises for debtors to out of the blue give up on some of their money - its a sign of a scam. Why would debtors reduce the debt by 60%? He's paying, he can pay, he is not on the way to bankruptcy (or is he?)? Why did he do it to begin with?

Comment: +1 Student Loans survive bankruptcy, they are not settling for 50 or 60 cents on the dollar. That was my clue.

Comment: +1 - They did send him letters, had a website, and a legit phone number.  But I agree anytime it looks to good to be true it probably is.  You hit all of the points I was going to hit on if no one answered today. As for why he did it because it was too good to pass up he said.

Comment: @Chad It will take me ~1/2 hour to set up a nicely looking web site, "legit" phone number and letters with fancy letterhead. And I don't even have to be in the same country (or continent, hint hint) to do that.

Comment: > `I believe no-one who's in a legal line of business would tell you to default voluntarily on your obligations.`

Do you mean that in general or for this specific question?  There are lots of times when a default makes sense and plenty of very smart and very legal people would recommend it.  
  
You are right though in this question.  Just simply halting payments without discussing it with the company is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @Pablitorun breach of contract, in general, is an extreme step. I do believe that in general, unless you yourself know that you cannot afford the payments, anyone who's telling you to default on your obligation is scamming (you or someone else). the fact that they're smart or there are many of them is irrelevant. You can't be stupid if you want to scam people.

Comment: @littleadv so do you think http://www.youwalkaway.com/ is a scam?  I just don't think telling you to default is a dead give away of a scam in the making.  Also, I forgot to add the +1 to my previous comment.

Comment: @Pablitorun I don't know if you noticed, but I listed several "give aways" in my answer, not one. The link you suggested deals with foreclosures. It is a case of a secured loan, where the lender knows upfront that he either gets the money or the property. I do think its immoral, and ultimately they encourage people to do damage to themselves and others. While the OP showed a clear case of fraud, your example might not be classified as something "illegal" - but then again, some scams are legal and are based on the stupidity of men.

Comment: @littleadv I liked your answer, I am really not trying to criticize  it.  The propriety and morality of a strategic default is just a hobby horse of mine.  I argue this with family and friends all the time.  It angers me that we as a society let corporations off the hook for any sort of morality when making financial decisions like a strategic default or letting people go, and those same corporations use guilt as a tool to hang the consumers.

Comment: +1 @Pablitorun a tangent to the original question, so I won't go on. But agreed.

Comment: @Pablitorun I think that you're right about the discontent with what we allow the corporations to get away with, but I don't think the solution is to allow *anyone* to get away with these things, I'd rather *no-one* to get away with them. Justifying "strategic default" is in my opinion similar to justifying a "strategic theft". I don't care if its a corporation that does it or an individual, its immoral all the same.

Comment: @littleadv: this is the first time I read of duck typing being applied to finance, and it sounded awesome :-D

Comment: @littleadv unfortunately only the force of law in enforcing contracts is what a significant portion of our population and almost all of our corporations will adhere too.  You are in good company in arguing the immorality of a strategic default....I argue this point with a lot of people I know are smarter than me.

Comment: My classic example is a term life policy I had for 5 years.  I went on a 3 week vacation and forgot to pay the premium.  After those three weeks they agreed to reinstate the policy if I reapplied for it.  What do you want to bet that if I had developed heart disease or cancer in the intervening 5 years they wouldn't renew the policy?  They would be perfectly in their rights to refuse the policy, but I would consider that an immoral act.  I just feel that we should all be operating under the same rules. (I went with a different insurance company for a new term life policy.)

Comment: @Pablitorun - You missed your payment.  You defaulted not your company.  The company did not just decide to cancel your policy because you went on vacation.  A better comparison would be the company deciding not to pay out on a policy because it will cost them a lot of money to honor their obligation.  Can you imagine how that would play out.

Comment: @Chad that is exactly my point.  They were fully within their contractual and legal obligations, and I don't fault them for it.....just like someone who turns their house over to the bank....also sorry to clutter up the comments, I wish I could find the button to turn the rest into a discussion..

Comment: @Pablitorun note that in Chad's example, the collateral was a car (which can be seized when you default on the loan, but will probably cost much less than the money owned), and **nothing** for student loan. What can the lender take, your education? So voluntary ("strategic") default on such loans is basically **stealing**, because unlike with houses (in your earlier example), with cars and with nothing the lender has **zero** chance of recovering the investment.

Comment: @Pablitorun  With your example of missing a payment on the policy - I understand your frustration, but in this case the insurance company was ok (even reinstated the policy, didn't have to), and you were the "bad" guy. Unintentionally, but still - you were wrong. Nothing immoral here on both sides. Expecting the insurance company to "forgive" one missed payment lays in the area of customer service, not morality.

Comment: @littleadv to play devil's advocate what if I missed my payment because I was in the hospital, or was in a coma?  What about medical insurance companies that deny coverage for an expensive condition because you were previously diagnosed with a foot fungus. I would agree that if you have the means to pay then defaulting on a student loan would probably full under immorality, but what if it was pay the student loan or keep the heat on for my children?

Comment: @Pablitorun there should be a clause in the contract to answer you that. If there's none - tough luck. Make a recurring bill-pay or auto-pay to make sure it doesn't happen to you. Re denying coverage because of a previous condition, IMHO this is no longer legal thanks to ObamaCare, otherwise - I would sue their asses in court and let the jurors handle it. If its paying the loan or feeding your children - no dilemma there - feed the children. That was not the situation in Chad's question.

Comment: My key point in all this is no company is going to look past its contractual obligations in dealing with you, its customer or supplier.  They shouldn't because they have a fiduciary duty to their employees and investors.  

I don't think you should do anything beyond what is contractually obligated for the same reason.  (In this case your heirs would be your fiduciary dependents.)

For instance I always pay my bills on time, but it is because it would cost more to me in dealing with a default that I could pay and loss of credit in the future.  

In summary it is not personal it is business.

Comment: I won't respond again as I think I have made the point I was trying to make, but everyone else has equally valid points.  Sorry if I cluttered your answer or pestered you.

Comment: @Pablitorun - defaulting is not within your contractual obligations, its **breaking** your contractual obligations. Some loans (those that are secured) define what will the lender do in this case (car repossession, foreclosure on your house, etc). Some don't, but in both cases not paying is **breach** of contract, not a contractual obligation. When you have the choice of either eat or pay - you don't starve, you default. But if you're OK financially, defaulting "strategically" is **stealing**, like denying your coverage because "we don't feel like it".

Comment: @littleadv One last comment I swear.  Your last comment was exactly right I was getting a little too hung up on contractual obligations.  The bigger picture is that companies do a cost analysis of following contracts and obligations or breaking contracts as well.  See: (The Ford Pinto)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Pinto#Allegations_and_lawsuits] this is a classical example, but a similar process happens with every single product ever released.

Comment: @Littleadv - I agree if your choice is "Eat or starve" Choose eat.  But if your choice is Eat Steak or eat mac and cheese and pay bill you pay the bill and eat mac and cheese.  I have been there you live paycheck to paycheck and just barely get by.  Then a big bill hits you have to decide who to pay.  There is no right or wrong answer in that case.

Comment: @Pablitorun reading the article, it appears that you've chosen a rather bad example. Seems like the "Pinto Memo" you're referring to was actually unrelated to the context of our discussion. Nevertheless I agree that it happens, and I agree that its bad. What I'm saying is that encouraging individuals to behave like that will only make matters worse.

Comment: @Pablitorun That has nothing to do with paying your bills.  Ford didn't just decide they did not want to pay those families for their loss.  Ford didn't come and say we are taking away your car even though you paid.  They screwed up and underestimated the risk... it happens.

Answer (score 6):

I think in such situations a good rule of thumb may be - if you are asked to pay significant sums of money upfront before anything is done, stop and ask yourself, what would you do if they don't do what they promised? They know who you are, but usually most you know is a company name and phone number. Both can disappear in a minute and what are you left with?

If they said they'd pay off the debt and issue the new loan - fine, let them do it and then you pay them. If they insist on having money upfront without delivering anything - unless it's a very big and known and established company you probably better off not doing it. Either it's a scam or in the minuscule chance they are legit you still risking too much - you're giving money and not getting anything in return.

Comment: -1 because most of the consolidation companies simply finance the upfront fees that they charge.  Even the some(if not all) of the  non profits  charge fees for the consolidation.  Being asked to pay those upfront is not necessarily a sign of shady business practice.  Documents were sent that made it look official and above board(to my friend I dont trust extend this much trust to my mom let alone some faceless person on the phone).  I agree you should understand what those payments are for before you send them though.

Comment: Not necessarily but it makes very easy for them to cheat you. So if you are dealing with somebody you never heard about before and the most you have for your money is a paper with empty promises - not a good position to be in.

Comment: Personally I think that the vast majority of debt consolidation companies are screwing you.  This one was just out right fraud.  From what I have gathered the nature of debt consolodation firms means that this fraud is not terribly uncommon.

Comment: @Chad, not surprisingly, they're preying the weak.